# Tags for gravity (force) and Gravity (film)

Tags: discussion, tags

Tag wise, how do we distinguish between [gravity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitation) (the force) and [Gravity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravity_%28film%29) (the film)?

Sample: *[Watching “Gravity” reminded me of a short story I read in the 60s, but can't place now](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/41293)*

Comment: [gravity--physics] and [gravity-imaginar

Answer (score 8):

I suggest we do the same thing we did with [alien](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/alien) and [alien-1979](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/alien-1979).  Make a new [gravity-2013](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gravity-2013) for the film.  Discussions of the force should go to [gravity](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gravity).

Comment: Or include the tag [tag:movie] with a question relating to the film Gravity

Comment: @JackBNimble And what happens when the question is about gravity in a different film?

Comment: The universe stops.